# How to send receipt for invoice via Stripe API

Tags: stripe-payments

I'd like to send the customer a Stripe pre-built invoice receipt email when or after their invoice is marked as "paid_out_of_band". There doesn't seem to be a way in the API to replicate the behaviour of the "Send Receipt" button for invoices via the Dashboard: https://stripe.com/docs/receipts#manually-send-receipts-from-the-dashboard

I know it is possible if I used the PaymentIntent which is generated by the Invoice, however this is only available when the invoice is finalised. In this use case the user can edit their order and return to checkout, I'd prefer that we're not creating multiple invoices and finalising them each time this happens. To resolve this I am using a separate PaymentIntent, updating it until the user clicks confirm, then generating the Invoice once the we get the `payment_intent.succeeded` webhook. You can't link the Invoice and PaymentIntent up this way sadly so I simply cross reference them in the metadata for both objects.

I know I can send my own email with a link to the online receipt which exists on the Invoice but I would prefer to use the pre-built Stripe versions.

Comment: Have you been able to do it? I'm looking for the same answer.

Comment: I think we just stick for this now: "I know I can send my own email with a link to the online receipt which exists on the Invoice"

Comment: @Omar, unfortunately not! I haven't been able do achieve what I'm after and as Clode says, I my original fallback is what I ended up sticking with.

Comment: We ended up sending the receipts manually based on the purchase webhook.

Answer (score 3):

I have the similar problem before, and I did handle it by retrieving the payment receipt email html that available in the ["charge" event object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object), then send it as a html body for your email sender.

For example, in my case using django & djstripe:

```
import stripe
import requests

from typing import Union
from djstripe import webhooks
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

stripe.api_key = "xxxx"


def get_stripe_payment_receipt_html(
    invoice_or_payment_intent_data: dict,
) -> Union[str, None]:
    """
    function to retrieve the html text of payment receipt from stripe.
    :param `invoice_or_payment_intent_data` is dict of paid invoice or
            payment intent data that has "charge" or "latest_charge" id.
    :return html string or None
    """
    if (
        isinstance(invoice_or_payment_intent_data, dict)
        and invoice_or_payment_intent_data
    ):
        charge_id: Union[str, None] = invoice_or_payment_intent_data.get(
            "charge"
        ) or invoice_or_payment_intent_data.get("latest_charge")
        if not charge_id:
            return None

        try:
            charge_data = stripe.Charge.retrieve(charge_id)
            receipt_url: Union[str, None] = charge_data.get("receipt_url")
            if receipt_url:
                try:
                    response = requests.get(receipt_url, timeout=20)
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                        return response.text
                except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
                    ...
        except (
            stripe.error.RateLimitError,
            stripe.error.InvalidRequestError,
            stripe.error.AuthenticationError,
            stripe.error.APIConnectionError,
            Exception,
        ):
            ...
    return None



@webhooks.handler("invoice.payment_succeeded")
def invoice_payment_succeeded(event, **kwargs):
    invoice_data: dict = event.data["object"]

    ...

    html_message = get_stripe_payment_receipt_html(invoice_data)
    if html_message is not None:
        try:
            message = EmailMessage(
                subject="Receipt from Foobar"
                body=html_message,
                from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                to=[user.email],
                bcc=[default_email],
                reply_to=[default_email],
            )
            message.content_subtype = "html"
            message.send()
        except Exception as error:
            ...
    else:
        # using own payment receipt template
        ...



@webhooks.handler("payment_intent.succeeded")
def payment_intent_succeeded(event, **kwargs):
    payment_intent_data: dict = event.data["object"]

    ...

    html_message = get_stripe_payment_receipt_html(payment_intent_data)

    ...do the same as previous script
```